# how to pass ת הו נבדוק את הו נבדוק את הו נבדוק את הו נבדוק את הו text in url?

Tags: php, codeigniter, text

How to pass the different language text in url using the codeigniter url helper

Comment: Look into using `urlencode`

Answer (score 0):

Stated in [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) only US-ASCII letters and a couple of specialchars are allowed in an URL.

To use such a text you have to encode it first using urlencode(). Please note that the output looks similar to this:

> D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%95+%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A7+%D7%90%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%95+%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A7+%D7%90%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%95+%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A7+%D7%90%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%95+%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A7+%D7%90%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%95

To receive the initial text you have to use urldecode() afterwards.